# golang check tcp port open

Tags: go, networking

I need to check if remote address has specific TCP ports open or not. 
I have chosen to use golang for this purpose.
Here is my attempt so far:

```
func raw_connect(host string, ports []string) {
  for _, port := range ports {
     timeout := time.Second
     conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", host + ":" + port, timeout)
     if err != nil {
        _, err_msg := err.Error()[0], err.Error()[5:]
        fmt.Println(err_msg)
     } else {
        msg, _, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
           if err == io.EOF {
              fmt.Print(host + " " + port + " - Open!\n")
           }
        } else {
           fmt.Print(host + " " + port + " - " + string(msg))
        }
        conn.Close()
     }
   }
 }
```

This is working just fine for TCP port when application (such as SSH) returns first a string, I read it and print it with no time.

However, when the application above TCP is waiting for command from the client first (such as HTTP), there is a timeout (`if err == io.EOF` clause).

This timeout is quite long. I would need to know immediately if the port is open or not.

Is there a more suitable technique for this purpose ?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To check the port, you can check if the connection was successful. For example:

```
func raw_connect(host string, ports []string) {
    for _, port := range ports {
        timeout := time.Second
        conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", net.JoinHostPort(host, port), timeout)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Connecting error:", err)
        }
        if conn != nil {
            defer conn.Close()
            fmt.Println("Opened", net.JoinHostPort(host, port))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that in case of error the `conn` variable will still be differnet from `nil` ? Just wonder why not to use `if.else if` statement.

Comment: No, it's not possible. It can be ```if.else if``` or only ```if.else```. I think It doesn't matter

Comment: This is not working, at least nowadays, I just put any ports and even if it is closed it still said it is opened. This just ping the server I guess

Comment: @Madeo, maybe you have all the ports open. It is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check multiple port examples

```
func tcpGather(ip string, ports []string) map[string]string {
    // check emqx 1883, 8083 port

    results := make(map[string]string)
    for _, port := range ports {
        address := net.JoinHostPort(ip, port)
        // 3 second timeout
        conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", address, 3*time.Second)
        if err != nil {
            results[port] = "failed"
            // todo log handler
        } else {
            if conn != nil {
                results[port] = "success"
                _ = conn.Close()
            } else {
                results[port] = "failed"
            }
        }
    }
    return results
}
```

Comment: Does it work for UDP as well? I have tried it, but whatever port I put it always tells me it is open.

Comment: Telnet is an application that operates using the TCP protocol. UDP connectivity can not be tested using Telnet.